# ENUM validation spring expression language

Tags: spring, validation, enums, instanceof, spring-el

I am trying to validate a json field which internally is mapped to ENUM `businessType` internally in service. I am unable to write logic in SpEL to assert that `business_type` json field is one of the `businessType` Enums

I tried using `instanceof` but it only validates if input is an 'instance of' BusinessDetails class, not that if it is one of the ENUMS in BusinessDetails.BusinessType

`<property name="isValid" value="(#element.businessType instanceof (com.paypal.platform.ops.model.BusinessDetails$BusinessType))" />`

Please suggest how can i validate the input to be one of the defined ENUM types. 
Thanks for your input!

Comment: Can you provide some kind of sample code of your enum and json object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collection Selection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-selection) to filter the list of `BusinessType.values()` according to your `#element.businessType`:

```
T(com.paypal.platform.ops.model.BusinessDetails$BusinessType).values().?[name()==#element.businessType].length==1
```

If the filtered array is not empty then your `#element.businessType` must be valid, otherwise the array would be empty.